# No crop option for New Profile Picture?

Tags: support

Today I've tried to change my profile picture of DA. I'm sure that the 'Change Picture' functionality has been changed.

I remember that earlier we had an option (but not sure) to crop the new uploaded picture. But it's gone now. Now if I try to upload a new image (ofcourse not too large dimensions) it's being set to 128*128 which is weird.

IMO, It's difficult to upload the exact dimensions to fit the user profile picture.

Comment: Yea, gone for me too. Don't know why.